# How to override Apache keep-alive header using php?

Tags: php, apache, http, web

in my httpd.conf there is:

```
KeepAliveTimeout 1
```

I'm trying to override Apache KeepAliveTimeout setting in a **single** php script (not in the entire server) so I have a php script with:

```
header("Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100");
```

but it doesn't seem to make any difference. still I get in the response:

```
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=50
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Hi, have you found anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. It's there in place for  a valid reason.

[Apache v2.2 Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html)

### KeepAliveTimeout Directive

> The number of seconds Apache will wait for a subsequent request before
>   closing the connection. Once a request has been received, the timeout
>   value specified by the **Timeout** directive applies.
>
> Setting **KeepAliveTimeout** to a high value may cause performance
>   problems in **heavily loaded servers**. The higher the timeout, the more
>   server processes will be kept occupied waiting on connections with
>   idle clients.

Comment: I don't see that documentation says that this is not possible. I know what keep-alive is, and I'm aware of the implications. That's exactly why I want to change KeepAliveTimeout for only one single php script, which is requested every few seconds. In the current state, the user creates new connections every few seconds. I would like it to reuse the first connection

Comment: Ability to control resides with Apache. Say if it's allowed then what's the point of keeping it? Then it ought to be called `DefaultKeepAliveTimeout`. If server is yours, why not increase at Apache?

Comment: As I said, increasing the value in httpd.conf will increase the value for **all** transactions. As you wrote before, there is performance hit when setting high value for all of the transactions. That's why I would like to do it for a specific php script.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in the `.htaccess` file combined with a `FilesMatch` directive.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200566/keep-alive-feature-in-htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Connection: close');
// other php code here...
// ...
```

[From RFC 2616, Section 14.10:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10)

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to
> signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
> response. For example,
>
> ```
>    Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that
> the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1)
> after the current request/response is complete.
>
> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections
> MUST    include the "close" connection option in every message.

Related: [What does “Connection: close” mean when used in the response message?](https://serverfault.com/a/790199/128858)