# some information on keep-alive http header

Tags: apache, http-headers, keep-alive

The server that my website is located on it, send these two http headers:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive:timeout=5
```

As you can see, there is no `max` in `Keep-Alive` header. isn't it going to cause any problem? what is the default value for max?
And another question, I don't have access to apache config, how can I increase `timeout`?
Once I contacted the host manager, he said it's too *odd* and *strange* to manipulate the apache confing! REALLY IS IT? any idea?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Keep-alive header clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592698/keep-alive-header-clarification). It is up to the server when it closes the connection anyway, the `timeout` and `max` parameters are an indication, not a hard line. If the server is busy, it can close connections arbitrarily.

To modify the server settings locally, see [Using keep-alive feature in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200566/keep-alive-feature-in-htaccess). You can do so in `.htaccess` if the host allows you to.

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster. I read the two links you provided. It seems my host doesn't allow modifying keep-alive header in htaccess. Right now, I figured out that the server is **not returning** `keep-alive` headers. The headers in my question, are the response header from the proxy I am using! Although the server doesn't return `Connection` and `keep-alive` header, I can download files simultaneously from the website. Could you explain, why is this happening??! Thanks.

Comment: @Sattar keep-alive is  for _successive_ requests. With or without it, you can always fire simultaneous requests, unless server software prevents that.